# How to include a pageURL in a html template of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to include a extend pageUrl in a html template of my angularjs directive. Here is a simplest example for my case.

```
angular.module('pageInclude', [])
    .directive('pageInclude', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                extUrl: '='
            },
            template: "<div><h1>Page Include</h1><ng-include src=\"'{{extUrl}}'\"></ng-include></div>"
        }
    });
```

My Html code is:

```
<page-include ext-url="example/extendForm.html"></page-include>
```

Then I got following error:

> Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: '{{extUrl}}'
>   Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate
>   multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.  See
>   http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$interpolate/noconcat?p0='%7B%7BextUrl%7D%7D'
>       at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
>       at $interpolate (angular.js:10152)
>       at addAttrInterpolateDirective (angular.js:8101)
>       at collectDirectives (angular.js:7203)
>       at compileNodes (angular.js:7035)

Are there any way to make this case work? Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
extUrl: '='
```

to

```
extUrl: '@'
```

or change attr value to

```
ext-url="'example/extendForm.html'"
```

[example](http://jsbin.com/kidiwobafu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I've tried this way but it still doesn't work. The main reason is the the <ng-include src="'extUrl''> can not work in a directive template.

Comment: i add example in fiddle

Comment: Thank for Tek's example. It works. My mistake is to add the ' inside the src attribute of ng-include.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes

```
scope:{
  extUrl:'@'
}
```

and write the template as

```
template: "<div><h1>Page Include</h1><ng-include src=\"{{extUrl}}\"></ng-include></div>"
```